# MLR - Resampling of cox model

Tags: cox-regression, mlr

If I train a single Cox PH model in mlr, I can print a summary that shows the statistical significance of each predictor as shown below. But if I use resampling eg 5-fold cross validation, is there any way to get this information, perhaps aggregated over the 5 iterations or even just separately for each iteration?

Training a single model:

```
surv.task <- makeSurvTask(data = bb_imp, target = c("timeToEvent", "status"))
surv.lrn <- makeLearner(cl="surv.coxph", predict.type="response")
blood_coxph_base <- train(surv.lrn, surv.task) 
mod <- getLearnerModel(blood_coxph_base)
summary(mod)

Call:
survival::coxph(formula = f, data = data)

n= 873, number of events= 82 

                   coef  exp(coef)   se(coef)      z Pr(>|z|)    
Glucose       1.336e-01  1.143e+00  1.320e-01  1.012 0.311516    
Urate        -1.293e+00  2.745e-01  2.227e+00 -0.581 0.561572    
HDLChol      -7.635e-01  4.660e-01  1.670e+00 -0.457 0.647556    
LDLChol      -3.796e-01  6.841e-01  1.645e+00 -0.231 0.817495    
HCS           8.513e-02  1.089e+00  2.830e-02  3.009 0.002625 ** 
CARO          1.681e-01  1.183e+00  1.875e-01  0.897 0.369947    
CRP           4.701e-02  1.048e+00  4.232e-02  1.111 0.266691    
Creatinine   -8.598e-03  9.914e-01  6.450e-03 -1.333 0.182541    
Fructosamine  1.022e-02  1.010e+00  3.041e-03  3.360 0.000780 ***
IL1          -1.225e-01  8.847e-01  7.212e-02 -1.699 0.089396 .  
IL8          -2.137e-03  9.979e-01  1.059e-02 -0.202 0.840124    
Insulin      -3.182e-02  9.687e-01  2.323e-02 -1.370 0.170685    
MIC1          7.394e-04  1.001e+00  2.071e-04  3.571 0.000356 ***
VitD         -2.104e-05  1.000e+00  4.867e-03 -0.004 0.996551    
---
Signif. codes:  0 '***' 0.001 '**' 0.01 '*' 0.05 '.' 0.1 ' ' 1

Concordance= 0.713  (se = 0.033 )
Rsquare= 0.067   (max possible= 0.697 )
Likelihood ratio test= 60.37  on 31 df,   p=0.001
Wald test            = 64.67  on 31 df,   p=4e-04
Score (logrank) test = 65.66  on 31 df,   p=3e-04
```

Resampling:

```
rdesc <- makeResampleDesc(method="CV", iters=5, stratify=TRUE)
r = resample("surv.coxph", surv.task, rdesc, models=TRUE)
r

Resample Result
Task: bb_imp
Learner: surv.coxph
Aggr perf: cindex.test.mean=0.5854492
Runtime: 0.149925
```

I know that setting models=TRUE saves the individual models but I am not sure how to access them. I tried

```
summary(r$models[1])
```

but only got:

```
     Length Class        Mode
[1,] 8      WrappedModel list
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Models is a list. So you have to run `summary(getLearnerModel(r$models[[1]]))`.

Alternatively you can use `lapply` or similar functions:

```
all_summaries = lapply(r$models, function(x) summary(getLearnerModel(x)))
```